# How to Implement an Optimized Coordinate based Data Structure?

Tags: c++, data-structures, position, maps, rectangles

I don't know if such a structure already exists, but I'm wondering if there is something similar to a Map/Hash that has the following behavior:

- when an item is assigned into the map, the developer provides a "rectangle object" (x, y, width, height) as a key to the item.
- if a provided rectangle overlaps with an existing rectangle-key of the map, the assignment does not occur.
- in order to retrieve the item, an x and y position is provided to the map, and the item with the rectangle that contains this position is returned.

Comment: You should look for [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)  implementations.

Comment: As @Eelke, look for R-Trees (or better R*Tree (RStarTrees), alternatively for Quadtrees.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything ready-made in the STL, but you can check the full list of containers [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

You could wrap your own with a custom implementation fairly easily.

How about a lightweight Rectangle:

```
struct Rectangle {
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

Then a container that holds rectangles and handles the logic of adding a retrieving them:

```
struct ContainerOfRectangles {
    std::vector<Rectangle> rectangles;

    void AddNew(Rectangle r)
    {
        if (/* some condition is true */)
        {
            rectangles.push_back(r);
        }
    }

    Rectangle GetRectangle(Rectangle referenceRect)
    {
        for (const auto& rectangle : rectangles)
        {
            if (/* some condition on referenceRect and rectangle */)
            {
                return rectangle;
            }
        }
        // Something here if the rectangle wasn't found
        return Rectangle{};
    }
};
```

You could exchange `vector` for some other container if you like.